# Reading Dataset from files where some might be missing

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to load files to TensorFlow Dataset where some files might be missing (in which case I want to replace these with zeroes).

The structure of directories that I'm trying to read data from is as follows:

```
   |-data
   |---sensor_A
   |-----1.dat
   |-----2.dat
   |-----3.dat
   |---sensor_B
   |-----1.dat
   |-----2.dat
   |-----3.dat
```

`.dat` files are .csv files with spacebar as a separator. The content of every file is a single, multi-row observation where the number of columns is constant (say 4) and the number of rows is unknown (timeseries data).

I've successfully managed to read every sensor data to a separate TensorFlow Dataset with the following code:

```py
import os
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

data_root_dir = "data"

modalities_to_use = ["sensor_A", "sensor_B"]
timestamps = [1, 2, 3]

for mod_idx, modality in enumerate(modalities_to_use):
    # Will produce: ['data/sensor_A/1.dat', 'data/sensor_A/2.dat', 'data/sensor_A/3.dat']
    filenames = [os.path.join(data_root_dir, modality, str(timestamp) + ".dat") for timestamp in timestamps]

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames,))


    def _parse_function_internal(filename):
        number_of_columns = 4
        single_observation = tf.read_file(filename)
        # Tokenise every value so we can cast these to floats later.
        single_observation = tf.string_split([single_observation], sep='\r\n ').values
        single_observation = tf.reshape(single_observation, (-1, number_of_columns))
        single_observation = tf.strings.to_number(single_observation, tf.float32)
        return filename, single_observation

    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function_internal)

    print('Result:')
    for el in dataset:
        try:
            # Filename
            print(el[0])
            # Parsed file content
            print(el[1])
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
```

which successfully prints out content of all three files for every sensor.

My problem is that some timestamps in the dataset might be missing. For instance if file `1.dat` in `sensor_A` directory will be missing I'm getting this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: mock_data\sensor_A\1.dat : The system cannot find the file specified.
; No such file or directory
     [[{{node ReadFile}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]
```

which is thrown in this line:

```
for el in dataset:
```

What I've tried to do is to surround the call to `tf.read_file()` function with try block but obviously it doesn't work as the error is not thrown when `tf.read_file()` is called, but when the value is fetched from the dataset. Later I want to pass this dataset to a Keras model so I can't just surround it with try block. Is there any workaround? Is that even supported?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem, sharing the solution just in case someone else will be struggling with it as well. I had to use additional list of booleans specifying whether the file actually exist and pass it into the mapper. Then using `tf.cond()` function we decide whether to read the file or mock the data with zeroes (or any other logic).

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

data_root_dir = "data"

modalities_to_use = ["sensor_A", "sensor_B"]
timestamps = [1, 2, 3]

for mod_idx, modality in enumerate(modalities_to_use):
    # Will produce: ['data/sensor_A/1.dat', 'data/sensor_A/2.dat', 'data/sensor_A/3.dat']
    filenames = [os.path.join(data_root_dir, modality, str(timestamp) + ".dat") for timestamp in timestamps]
    files_exist = [os.path.isfile(filename) for filename in filenames]

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, files_exist))


    def _parse_function_internal(filename, file_exist):
        number_of_columns = 4
        single_observation = tf.cond(file_exist, lambda: tf.read_file(filename), lambda: ' '.join(['0.0'] * number_of_columns))
        # Tokenise every value so we can cast these to floats later.
        single_observation = tf.string_split([single_observation], sep='\r\n ').values
        single_observation = tf.reshape(single_observation, (-1, number_of_columns))
        single_observation = tf.strings.to_number(single_observation, tf.float32)
        return filename, single_observation

    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function_internal)

    print('Result:')
    for el in dataset:
        try:
            # Filename
            print(el[0])
            # Parsed file content
            print(el[1])
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
```